# Jucys-murphy elements commute with each other.

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

In the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$, for $1<i<j\le n$, $X_i=(1\ i)+(2\ i)+...+(i-1\ i)$ and $X_j=(1\ j)+(2\ j)+...+(j-1\ j)$ commute with each other.

I have been trying to do it computationally by multiplying out each term but I am getting lost. Since there are transpositions that don't commute, I am finding it difficult to keep track. Please help me.

Comment: Hint: $X_j$ commutes with every element of the subalgebra $\mathbb{C}\left[S_{j-1}\right]$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg You are right, the same calculation $(mi)(mn)+(ni)(mn)=(mni)+(min)=(mn)(mi)+(mn)(ni)$ is involved, but in your way, you only need to do it once... 

I was wondering if there is a representation theory argument making use of the fact that $X_i$ is the difference of an element from the center $Z(\mathbb{C}[S_i])$ and one from the center $Z(\mathbb{C}[S_{i-1}])$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is one occasion, it might not be such a bad idea to do it computationally after all (that is, I am not aware of a better method). It is true that some transpositions don't commute, but we can pinpoint exactly which..:

The arbitrary elements in the expansions $X_iX_j$ and $X_jX_i$ are $(ki)(mj)$ and $(mj)(ki)$. These are definitely equal when the set $\{k,m,i,j\}$ has exactly $4$ elements. The only cases that are left are $k=m<i<j$ and $k<i=m<j$.

Therefore we have to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}(ki)(kj)+\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}(ki)(ij)=\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}(kj)(ki)+\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}(ij)(ki)$$

Notice however that $(ki)(kj)=(kji)=(ij)(ki)$ and $(kj)(ki)=kij=(ki)(ij)$, that is both expressions are equal to:$$\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}(kij)+(kji)$$

Anyway, I would like to see a better proof but I think at some point you'd have to do a similar computation. By the way, if you are studying [Jucys-Murphy elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jucys%E2%80%93Murphy_element), it's really worth it to see how [Okounkov and Vershik](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503040) use them to build the representation theory of the Symmetric group. These [notes](http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~mks/notes/vershik_okounkov.pdf) are helpful if you do decide to study the paper..

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to see this goes as follows: the $i$th Jucys-Murphy-Young element is the orbit sum
$$X_i=\sum_{1 \leq j < i} (ij)=\frac{1}{|S_{i-2}|}\sum_{w \in S_{i-1}} w(1i)w^{-1} $$ which commutes with $S_{i-1}$, and in particular with $X_1,\dots,X_{i-1}$.